# reduce coordinates for polygon matlab

Tags: algorithm, matlab

I have a set of coordinates representing some polygon. However, I need to reduce the number of coordinates while still staying as close as possible to the original polygons shape. For example, I need to cut one down to 20 points. Is there a known algorithm that does this? I am working in MATLAB if that helps.

The context of the problem is using bwboundaries in matlab to find the borders of multiple images. I need the number of points for each image to be the same.

Comment: You can select points that produce minimum area triangles with their neighbors. But maybe it's better do add points by splitting edges?

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/45342-polygon-simplification

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/34639-decimate-polygon